# My virtual machine can't ping itself

Tags: ros, ros-hostname, ros-indigo, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Ubuntu indigo 14.04 with Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.18 and I have a problem with my Virtual machine which can't ping itself but can ping all the network. Also, the other computers can ping each other but can't ping the virtual machine.
My network is composed by : 2 virtual machines (chloe and another one) on the main station, the main station, a first router, the second router in client mode, an Advantech computer on a robot and Ubuntu on this computer (efim).

So, from chloe, I can ping all of this stuff but not chloe itself. I had the issue : "Destination Host Unreachable" while I'm just pinging chloe itself.

In the settings, I choose NAT for the Virtual Machine.

Moreover, I tried a

```
roswtf
```

and I have the following warning :

```
  ROS_HOSTNAME may be incorrect: ROS_HOSTNAME [chloe] resolves to [192.168.0.6], which does not appear to be a local IP address ['127.0.0.1', '10.0.2.15', '192.168.1.2', '169.254.7.89'].
```

What I did after this is :
for main station

```
    export ROS_HOSTNAME=chloe
    export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://chloe:11311
```

for advantech

```
    export ROS_HOSTNAME=efim
    export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://chloe:11311
```

But after I have an error saying :

```
  ROS_MASTER_URI is not set for this machine
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304185/my-virtual-machine-can%27t-ping-itself/) by [kevinrossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/37720/kevinrossi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-25**:
So `ping 192.168.0.6` in a terminal doesn't work?

If so, this is not really a ROS question I'm afraid.

If this is a ROS question, then please provide more details on your network setup. We'll need full IP/netmask and network topology (ie: what is connected to what).

A diagram may help.

**Comment by [kevinrossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/37720/kevinrossi/) on 2018-09-25**:
Yes, ping 192.168.0.6 doesn't work in a terminal.

I have one diagram but I'm new and I can't add picture.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-25**:
re: attaching images: I've just given you sufficient karma for that.

re: `ping` doesn't work: that would point to an issue with your network configuration. Are you sure that is the correct IP?

**Comment by [Boregard](https://answers.ros.org/users/33549/boregard/) on 2018-09-25**:
may you post output of "ifconfig"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's okay now, the IP was wrong so I changed it in the settings and now it's working.
Thank you !

---

Originally posted by [kevinrossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/37720/kevinrossi/) with karma: 26 on 2018-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0